# 403 Forbidden Error when attempting to authenticate

Tags: oauth, botframework, azure-bot-service

I cloned and ran [24.bot-authentication-msgraph](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) to test authentication. I've updated the .bot file to put my app id and password as found https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. I've also updated CONNECTION_SETTING_NAME variable in bot.js.

**Edit**: I forked the repo so you can see my code and changes [here](https://github.com/AskYous/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph). Check out the last 3 commits to see my changes. I excluded my .bot file because it has my app password.

But the bot doesn't even try to authenticate me, and in the console, [I received a 403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6feI.png). It has no description or text with it.

[image]

Comment: And you configured your named OAuth provider client/secret in the Bot Framework Service?

Comment: Yes I did: https://i.imgur.com/oLp7M5U.png. I added it in my code too: https://i.imgur.com/Ucmoy1L.png

Comment: I've also added the app id and password to my .bot file: https://i.imgur.com/gxniYHf.png. That's all the changes I made since cloning it.

Comment: Can you share your start up code so I can see how you're loading your creds from the .bot file? (NOTE: please feel free to edit the question to include it there rather than try to fit it here in the comments as an image)

Comment: I don't know how to do that while hiding my app id and password. I'll upload my code but will exclude the .bot file.

Comment: Have you added your app id and password to the emulator?

Comment: @DrewMarsh I edited my question to include my code.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes, I didn't but I did give the emulator my .bot file so it can read it from there.

Comment: That doesn't look like the emulator's version of bot sample #24. What are you using to test this?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes, I tested it in the lastest version and a previous version of Microsoft's bot emulator. Here's a video I recorded: https://gfycat.com/UnlawfulBlaringIncatern.

Comment: You are fabulous and that was an excellent video. In the second emulator, there's a broken image link. That SHOULD resolve to a Bot Framework logo. Not sure why yet, but I have a feeling what's blocking that image is also blocking your bot.

Comment: @AskYous I cloned your repo, and set up a fresh bot following [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Everything worked fine for me. Do you have the "Use a sign-in verification code for OAuthCards" checked in Emulator > Settings (gear at bottom-left)?

Comment: @mdrichardson I checked it on but got the same results.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes, any idea how I can find out why that image failed? I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @mdrichardson, can you tell me where you got your app id and password? Was it from apps.dev.microsoft.com?

Comment: @AskYous Yes, you can get it from there. If you lost the password, just click "Generate New Password". You can also get them by opening your Resource Group in Azure, then Deployments > {yourBot} > Inputs and then getting `APPID` AND `APPSECRET`

Comment: I think I found the problem. I never set up ngRok (because it's blocked at my work). Is this needed?

Comment: Nevermind. I installed and configured it and got no luck.

Comment: @AskYous If you're still having trouble, I recommend starting over while following [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Again, I followed them exactly with your Repo and it worked just fine.

Comment: @AskYous If you go into your Azure Resource Group, then your Bot Channels Registration, then Settings, click your OAuth settings. If you then click "Test Connection", does it take you to the Token page?

Comment: And can you double-check the password in your .bot file? The one in the image from one of your earlier comments is too long if it's unencrypted and should end in a "=" if it is encrypted (using `msbot secret --new`)

Comment: @mdrichardson here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/BgjZiGs.png) from Azure. The password ends with a `B`. I pressed `Test Connection` and it gave me a token. It's the password I put in my .bot file. In the code, when it runs `BotConfiguration.loadSync(BOT_FILE, process.env.botFileSecret)`, `process.env.botFileSecret` is an empty string. I don't know if it's encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after doing some troubleshooting and intentionally trying to break my implementation, I figured out the issue.

You have two "apps", 1 "App Registration" in the [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) and 1 "Web App Bot/Bot Channels Registration" in your Azure Resource Group (or at least you should if you follow [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)):

1. An Azure AD v1 or v2 app created in [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#register-an-application-in-azure-ad) "**To create an Azure AD v1/v2 application**"
2. A Bot Channels Registration app created in [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#create-your-bot-on-azure) "**Create your bot on Azure**"

Based on your images, you're using your Azure AD v2 appId and appPassword in your `.bot` file, when you should be using your Bot Channels Registration bot's appId and appPassword, as described in [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#register-your-azure-ad-application-with-your-bot).

*Note: The Azure AD v2 appId and appPassword are only used when [editing your bot's Azure settings to add OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#register-your-azure-ad-application-with-your-bot).*

You can get your bot's appId and appPassword (which you need to place in your `.bot` file) in either of two ways:

- Via App Registration Portal

  1. Go to the [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) and click on your
     bot (NOT the Azure AD v1/v2 app).

     - If you named them similarly, you'll know you chose the wrong one if it has a Web Platform listed--that should only be in the Azure AD v1/v2
  2. It will list your appId and you can
     get a new password by clicking "Generate New Password"

or,

- Via Azure Portal

  1. Open your Resource Group in the [Azure
     portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/).
  2. Click Deployments
  3. Under "Deployment Name", click your Bot Channels Registration bot.
  4. Click Inputs. Your appId and appPassword is APPID and APPSECRET,
     respectively.

Comment: I really appreciate this and wish I didn't have to make you go through this work. You mentioned there are supposed to be two apps **in the app registration portal.** However, in the link to create the second app, it links to registering the first app **into Azure,** and **not** the app registration portal. I'm confused on this step. I already did both however. But I only have one app in apps.dev.microsoft.com.

Comment: I corrected the first link. Looks like I copy/pasted the wrong one. You do the first one in the App Registration Portal and the second in the Azure portal. After the Bot Channels Registration bot is fully deployed in Azure, it should automatically show up in the App Registration Portal, even though it was created in Azure.

Comment: So I deleted my OAuth Connection Setting and re-created it according to the directions in the second link. It seems that's all I had to do. However, I only see one app in `app.dev.microsoft.com` still. Perhaps I should delete this bot entirely and try again. This is getting too frustrating.

Comment: Do you have a Bot Channels Registration resource in Azure? That should automatically feed into the App Registration Portal after creation, but it's possible, I guess, that it isn't there. So long as everything works, I guess it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: I have no idea how to find that. I don't see a button or link or anything saying `Bot Registration Resources` in Azure.

Comment: Alright, maybe that's where we got lost. Go to the [Azure Portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com). Click "Resource Groups" on the left. Click on your resource group. Is there a "Bot Channels Registration" listed?

If not, Click Create a Resource in the upper-left. Search for "Bot Channels Registration". Click Create and create a Bot Channels Registration.

Follow [the remaining steps in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#to-register-an-azure-ad-v2-application).

Comment: I do have a resource group for my bot. Is it a bot channel registration? I don't know. I uploaded a screenshot of "Resource Groups" and "All Resources" [here](https://imgur.com/a/1VExDoV). All my resources are under that resource group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187218/discussion-between-mdrichardson-and-askyous).